# Can I programmatically set the condition in a `for` loop?

Tags: ios, for-loop, conditional-statements

I have an extensive amount of code inside a `for` loop.  I want to execute the loop either 0 to 9 ascending, or 9 to 0 descending, based on the boolean variable `countUp`.  It's easy to set the initial condition and the increment... but how can I programmatically set the condition (the operator being the problem)?

```
int startValue = _countUp ? 0 : 9;
int increment = _countUp ? 1 : -1;
// How do I define a condition ??? so that the following single line of code will work:

for (int i = startValue; ???; i = i + increment) {
  ...
```

I tried an NSString, which of course didn't work. I know there are solutions that place both loops in an `if-else` statement, i.e. defining the loop code as a function, and calling it with either the ascending or the descending `for` loop.  But is there an elegant way to just set the `for` loop programmatically?

Comment: Multiple good answers here; wish I could credit more than one.  I'll end up implementing Bryan's second solution, but RobP got to main issue about defining a condition conditionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about using a ternary operator? it's concise and readable and should do the trick.

```
for(int i = startValue; _countUp ? (i <= 9) : (i >=0); i = i + increment) {
```

Comment: +1 for directly answering question, and using the correct operator as OP asked.

Comment: Thanks, that does it.  Just out of curiosity, what type of variable is (i <= 9)?  What if I wanted to define it independently of the 'for' statement?

Comment: it's boolean, a true or false value. The condition inside the () of any `if()` needs to evaluate to a boolean, and the condition at A in `A ? B : C` also needs to evaluate to a boolean.

Answer (score 4):

one way is to added an `endValue`

```
int startValue = _countUp ? 0 : 9;
int increment = _countUp ? 1 : -1;
int endValue = _countUp ? 9 : 0;

for (int i = startValue; i != endValue; i = i + increment) {

}
```

or eaiser

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int value = _countUp ? i : 9 - i;
    // use value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just implement the ternary operator inside the for loop.

```
for (int i = _countUp ? 0 : 9; i != _countUp ? 9 : 0; i += _countUp ? 1 : -1) {

}
```